# Warning about invalid maven-metadata-nexus.xml during Maven install

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm getting the following warning when running `maven clean install` on my java project.

> [WARNING] The metadata .m2/repository/.../maven-metadata-nexus.xml is invalid: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: TEXT seen ...tent/groups/public/com/github/jnr/jffi/maven-metadata.xml&arubalp=... @3:147)

I'm using a Nexus as a Maven repository mirror which is configured in my settings.xml.

Comment: Please note that this is a "self-answer" question that is intended to be a generic answer. I could not find an existing answer to this and hope it might help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the `maven-metadata.xml` of one requested dependency ended up being corrupted.
My explanation is that during the builds the Nexus had some problems for some time but was responding to HTTP request but not with the correct response. It responded to the request of the maven-metadata.xml with the following response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; url=http://nexus..../content/groups/public/com/github/jnr/jffi/maven-metadata.xml&arubalp=8e10706d-9203-4643'>
</head>
</html>
```

Which got written as the maven-metadata.xml in the local Maven repository. This content is of cause not a valid content for a maven-metadata.xml file which caused the mentioned warning.

Deleting the dependency in the local Maven repository and getting it fresh from the Nexus resolved the problem for me but make sure that the Nexus it responding with the correct content by requesting the maven-metadata.xml via curl or in the browser (e.g. `curl -k https://nexus..../repository/central/com/github/jnr/jffi/maven-metadata.xml`).
A valid content should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
  <artifactId>jffi</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.2.17</latest>
    <release>1.2.17</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.11</version>
      ...
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20180516162549</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```